# How can I get the difference between two dates in hours, omitting the hours on weekends?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I need a function to check how many hours have passed between two dates, but if for example there is a weekend in between, then skip those hours.

Date 1: `moment('2022-05-27 20:00:00).tz('UTC')`

Date 2: `moment('2022-05-30 20:00:00).tz('UTC')`

Expected output: `24 hours`

Comment: This answer or that library might be useful:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37069478/16806649
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-business-days

Answer (score 1):

I get 25 if I do `i <= n` and 24 when I do `i < n`

But I do not use moment

Note that this should work across daylight savings changes in the locale you are in

```js
const d1 = new Date('2022-05-27 20:00:00')
const d2 = new Date('2022-05-30 20:00:00')
console.log(d1, d2)
let hours = 0;
for (let i = d1.getTime(), n = d2.getTime(); i < n; i += 3600000) {
  const d = new Date(i);
  if (![0, 6].includes(d.getDay())) hours++; 
}
console.log(hours)
```